Correr las migraciones en local afectan producción
Estuve haciendo cambios al sistema de manera local, descargué el sistema desde el hosting e hice unas migraciones, tambien el .env hice un cambio para que esté conectada a la base de datos local, pero al poner php artisan migrate me sale esta advertencia
Application In Production! Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
no estoy seguro de que si vaya a cambiar algo dentro del hosting que no es mio

lo que puede estar sucediendo es que tu aplicación esta marcada como "en producción". Eso se encuentra en el archivo
.env  en la linea
   APP_ENV=production

al inicio del archivo.
Puedes cambiar esa linea por
   APP_ENV=local

mientras trabajas.
Si no vas a subir de nuevo el archivo .env  lo puedes dejar así. En caso contrario tienes que volver a la linea original.
laravel te protege si es una aplicación en producción para que no hagas migraciones que pueden afectar a los datos en producción sin querer.
Espero que esto te ayude.  Saludos

Me olvide de decir que no afecta los datos en producción si configuras correctamente los datos de acceso a la base de datos . El mensaje se evita como te dije en la respuesta anterior
